# Declare and define inside namespace - Not sure if it works because it's correct or by accident

Tags: c++, namespaces

straight to the point
i have a .h file as follows

```
namespace ns
    {
    namespace n1
        {
        class a
            {funct();}
        class b
            {funct();}
        }
    namespace n2
        {
        class a
            {funct();}
        class b
            {funct();}
        }
    }
```

normally i would define the function in the .cpp file in this way:

```
int ns::n1::a::funct(){return 1;}
int ns::n1::b::funct(){return 1;}
int ns::n2::a::funct(){return 1;}
int ns::n2::b::funct(){return 1;}
```

Today i noticed this works as well as .cpp file

```
namespace ns
    {
    namespace n1
        {
        a::funct(){return 1;}
        b::funct(){return 1;}
        }
    namespace n2
        {
        a::funct(){return 1;}
        b::funct(){return 1;}
        }
    }
```

Which seems very helpful when organizing a .cpp file that has a tree of namespaces.

Is this standard or it just works by accident?

Comment: This is the expected behavior.  Just like you declared the class in a namespace you can define its members inside the namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this standard or it just works by accident?

It is correct, not the result of an accident. IMO it's also the better approach. I think it is better since you don't have to repeat the namespaces.

Comment: You could argue that there's a potential for the reader to be uncertain which namespace they're looking at, in a large file with multiple namespaces, but those two circumstances in conjunction are probably an indicator that you should split the code into multiple files.

Comment: @TimRandall, when a .h files gets large, it will definitely be better to split it into multiple .h files.